# Fatal Python Error: Segmentation Fault when running my own voice assistant program

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, google-aiy

I have an error when i run my custom voice assistant program on Raspberry Pi 3B .This script is made from two programs from examples(assistant_library_demo.py and cloud_speech.py).Consequently the script does the both functions from those examples. This is how the program code looks like:

This is for the voice assistant, that combines both functions of Google voice assistant and Google Cloudspeech API

```py
import argparse
import locale
import logging
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from gpiozero import Servo
import signal
import sys
from google.assistant.library.event import EventType
from aiy.assistant import auth_helpers
from aiy.assistant.library import Assistant
from aiy.board import Board, Led
from aiy.cloudspeech import CloudSpeechClient
import aiy.voice.tts


def get_hints(language_code):
    if language_code.startswith("en_"):
        return (
            "turn on the light",
            "turn off the light",
            "blink the light",
            "goodbye",
            "repeat after me",
            "lights on",
            "lights off",
            "minimum",
            "middle",
            "maximum",
        )
    return None


def locale_language():
    language, _ = locale.getdefaultlocale()
    return language


def process_event(led, event):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
    servo = Servo(6)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Assistant service example.")
    parser.add_argument("--language", default=locale_language())
    args = parser.parse_args()
    logging.info("Initializing for language %s...", args.language)
    hints = get_hints(args.language)
    client = CloudSpeechClient()
    logging.info(event)
    text = client.recognize(language_code=args.language, hint_phrases=hints)
    if "lights on" in text:
        GPIO.output(24, GPIO.HIGH)
    elif "lights off" in text:
        GPIO.output(24, GPIO.LOW)
    elif "maximum" in text:
        servo.max()
    elif "minimum" in text:
        servo.min()
    elif "middle" in text:
        servo.mid()
    if event.type == EventType.ON_START_FINISHED:
        led.state = Led.BEACON_DARK  # Ready.
        logging.info('Say "OK, Google" then speak, or press Ctrl+C to quit...')
    elif event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED:
        led.state = Led.ON  # Listening.
    elif event.type == EventType.ON_END_OF_UTTERANCE:
        led.state = Led.PULSE_QUICK  # Thinking.
    elif (
        event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED
        or event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_TIMEOUT
        or event.type == EventType.ON_NO_RESPONSE
    ):
        led.state = Led.BEACON_DARK
    elif (
        event.type == EventType.ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR
        and event.args
        and event.args["is_fatal"]
    ):
        main()


def main():
    credentials = auth_helpers.get_assistant_credentials()
    with Board() as board, Assistant(credentials) as assistant:
        for event in assistant.start():
            process_event(board.led, event)


if name == "main":
    main()
```

This is how error text looks like: The error text when i run the sketch from python shell:

```
Backend terminated (returncode: -11) 
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Thread 0x580fe470 (most recent call first): File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 297 in wait File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 549 in wait File "/opt/aiy/projects-python/src/aiy/board.py", line 208 in _run File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862 in run File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914 in _bootstrap_inner File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 882 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x76f66640 (most recent call first): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages-linux-armv7l/google/assistant/library/assistant.py", 
line 114 in exit File "/opt/aiy/projects-python/src/examples/voice/myassistant.py", 
line 96 in main File "/opt/aiy/projects-python/src/examples/voice/myassistant.py",
 line 99 in File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py",
 line 1232 in _execute_prepared_user_code File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", 
line 1158 in wrapper File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", 
line 1171 in wrapper File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", 
line 1219 in execute_source File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py",
 line 853 in _execute_source File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", 
line 840 in _execute_file File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", 
line 400 in _cmd_Run File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py",
line 217 in handle_command File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", 
line 162 in mainloop File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend_launcher.py", 
line 70 in Use 'Stop/Restart' to restart the backend ...
```

The error text when i run the sketch from terminal: `Segmentation fault`

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code? How are you running this code?  I'm not sure if it's just a typo in the question or in your real code, but an obvious error is at the bottom of your file,  `name == "main"` should be `__name__ == "__main__"`

Answer (score 0):

Thank everyone for your help, i fixed the problem by rewriting the whole code using different google demos